# How to disable "RMI TCP Connection" logging?

Tags: java, logging, rmi

I have specified a VM option of `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=SILENT` on start up of my `Tomcat` web app but I still see the following messages coming from `System.err` in my Server Output tab in IntelliJ:

> [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO
>   org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
>
> [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.CachingOperationNameGenerator
>   - Generating unique operation named: saveUserUsingPUT_1

What do I need to do to silence these "RMI TCP Connection" messages?  I would like to keep `ERROR` level messages if possible

Comment: They are off by default. Something somewhere must be *enabling* them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just put `slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar` in our codebase which uses a default log level of `info`.  I put a `simplelogger.properties` file into our codebase with a default log level of `error` and those "RMI TCP Connection" `info` and `warn` messages are gone.